# Int 32 true and BOOL true in swift

Tags: swift, ios8, boolean

What is the difference between

> Int32 true

and

> BOOL true

in swift .Int32 true to be used in which all situations?
[image]

Comment: The Int32 true doesn't belong to Swift. Can you show your imports?

Comment: Objective c project ported to swift actually using bridging header

Comment: @0x7fffffff I see that all the time (probably only in projects with used bridging headers).  My guess is it exists because of how strict Swift is with its types and because some very old libraries may simply not have a `Bool` type and *expect* an `Int32` (but perhaps document it as a "boolean").